# Trimming a numpy array in cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Currently I have the following cython function, modifies entries of a numpy array filled with zeros to sum non-zero values. Before I return the array, I would like to trim it and remove all the non-zero entries. At the moment, I use the numpy function `myarray = myarray[~np.all(myarray == 0, axis=1)]` to do so. I was wondering if there is (in general) a faster way to do this using a Cython/C function instead of relying on python/numpy. This is one of the last bits of pythonic interactions in my script (checked by using to `%%cython -a`). But I don't really know how to proceed with this problem. In general, i don't know a priori the number of nonzero elements in the final array.

```
cdef func():
   np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] myarray = np.zeros((lenpropen, 6)) 
   """
   computations
   """

   myarray = myarray[~np.all(myarray == 0, axis=1)]
   return myarray
```

Thanks to @Jérôme Richard for his comments. based on that (if my understanding is correct) I tried to implement the erase-remove idiom. Sample code given below.

```
myarray = np.zeros((5000,6))
myarray[2] = [1,1,1,1,1,1]
@cython.boundscheck(False)  # Deactivate bounds checking                                                                  
@cython.wraparound(False)   # Deactivate negative indexing.                                                               
@cython.cdivision(True)     # Deactivate division by 0 checking.
cdef erase_remove( np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] myarray):
    cdef int idx 
    cdef int cursor = 0
    cdef int length_arr = 5000
    for idx in range(5000):
    
        if myarray[idx,0]!=0 and myarray[idx,1]!=0 and myarray[idx,2]!=0 and myarray[idx,3]!=0 and myarray[idx,4]!=0 and  myarray[idx,5]!=0:
            myarray[cursor,0] = myarray[idx,0]
            myarray[cursor,1] = myarray[idx,1]
            myarray[cursor,2] = myarray[idx,2]
            myarray[cursor,3] = myarray[idx,3]
            myarray[cursor,4] = myarray[idx,4]
            myarray[cursor,5] = myarray[idx,5]
            cursor = cursor +1
        else:
            continue
    return  myarray[0:cursor]    
start = timer()
myarray= erase_remove(myarray)
end = timer()
print("final", myarray)
print("time", end-start)
```

This yields the output

```
final [[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
time 1.1235475540161133e-05
```

Compared to

```
myarray = np.zeros((5000,6))
print(myarray)

myarray[2] = [1,1,1,1,1,1]
print(myarray)
start = timer()
myarray = myarray[~np.all(myarray == 0, axis=1)]
end = timer()
print(myarray)
print("time", end-start)
```

which yields output

```
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
time 0.0006445050239562988
```

Comment: I changed the indentation of the return. Otherwise the algorithm would not work (only one item would be filtered). Besides this, you do not need the `else`+`continue`. Overall, it seems great :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the highest dimension contains always a small number of element like 6, then your code is not the best one.

First of all, `myarray == 0`, `np.all` and `~` creates **temporary arrays** that introduces some additional overhead as they needs to be written and read back. The overhead is dependent of the this of the temporary array and the biggest one is `myarray == 0`.

Moreover, Numpy calls perform some **unwanted checks** that Cython is not able to remove. These checks introduce a constant time overhead. Thus, is can be quite big for small input arrays but not big input arrays.

Additionally, the code of `np.all` can be faster if it would know the exact size of the last dimension which is not the case here. Indeed, the loop of `np.all` could theoretically be **unrolled** since the last dimension is small. Unfortunately, *Cython does not optimize Numpy calls* and Numpy is compiled for a variable input size, so *not known at compile-time*.

Finally, **the computation can be parallelized if `lenpropen` is huge** (otherwise this will not be faster and could actually be slower). However, note that a parallel implementation requires the computation to be done in two steps: `np.all(myarray == 0, axis=1)` needs to be computed in parallel and then you can create the resulting array and write it by computing `myarray[~result]` in parallel. In sequential, you can directly overwrite `myarray` by **filtering lines in-place** and then produce a view of the filtered lines. This pattern is known as the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom). Note that this assume the array is **contiguous**.

To conclude, a faster implementation consists writing 2 nested loops iterating on `myarray` with a constant number of iterations for the innermost one. Regarding the size of `lenpropen`, you can either use a sequential in-place implementation base on the erase-remove idiom, or a parallel out-of-place implementation with two steps (and a temporary array).

Comment: Thank you for your response. The arrays aren't particularly huge at most np.zeros((5000,6)); so I have been thinking of implementing the sequential implementation you described. Unfortunately, forgive my ignorance, but I don't quite follow, the discussion of the erase-remove idiom. could you perhaps elaborate on that?

Comment: @jcp The idea is to use a `i`-based loop iterating over the row and maintain a `cursor` variable to the last filtered row starting from 0. When you find a row where the `~np.all`-like condition is true, you copy the row at `array[cursor]` and then increment `cursor`. Otherwise, nothing need to be done (discarded row). In the end, the filtered row will be "moved" in the beginning of `array`. This is the remove step. The erase step consists in simply returning `array[0:cursor]`. Is this more clear?

Comment: yes, thank you that was very helpful (and clever algorithm). If my understanding is correct, I have updated the original post with my implementation of the erase_remove method.